# How can I restore my iCloud deleted e-mails?

Tags: icloud, email, restore

I have a mail account like xx@me.com. Due to slow working and non-responding computer, I accidentally erased my inbox and trash on iCloud.

Is there any option that I can recover them?

Answer (score 2):

You say "computer" but don't specify what, I will assume that you mean you have a Mac also, in which case, on the assumption that you run Time Machine (please, *everyone*, **make backups!**) then offline copies should be in your backups.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into icloud.com with your Apple ID and password. If the messages are no longer there, then there is no recovery option.